# "Deep equality" test and hashCode()

Tags: java, object

Suppose a class `MyClass` has 3 variables, `a`,`b` and `c`. This class also overrides hashCode() that calculates return value using Joshua Bloch's approach.

Assuming the above, would it be correct to assume that `MyClass()` and `new MyClass()` are deeply equal if their hashcodes match?

For the purposes of the example, assume that both objects are initialized with the same parameters

Comment: You may want to clarify what Josh Bloch's approach is for those who are unfamiliar.

Comment: Yeah just out of curiosity what would that be? I mean it's obvious (pigeons and so) that a hashCode can't generally be unique so I assume it's some method to create a perfect hash for a limited, known dataset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly not.

`hashCode` is required to yield the same value for equivalent objects, but different objects may yield the same value. So, the following is a correct (but inefficient) `hashCode` implementation:

```
public int hashCode()
{
    return 42;
}
```

Even when you know a specific hashing method is used, it is a bad idea to assume `hashCode` is perfect: later, some refactoring/subclass might replace the `hashCode` implementation with something else. If you want this, create a `perfectHashCode` method that does always return a perfect hashcode, and use that for implementing `hashCode`

To answer your initial question: no, even Bloch's approach afaics does not yield a perfect hashCode, because (because of wrapping over MAXINT) 2 different paths might eventually collide into the same hash code.

This is easy to imagine: say your object holds 2 integers. The hash code is only 1 integer. So it can never yield a different value for each combination of 2 integers.

Comment: Read the OP's second sentence: _"This class also overrides hashCode() that calculates return value using Joshua Bloch's approach."_

Comment: You are, of course, right. Extended the answer to explain why you cannot make that assumption for his implementation, either.

Answer (score 0):

You can never assume two objects are equal if their hash codes match. The hash codes being equal only means that the objects *may* be equal and that `equals` must be called to determine for sure. The hash codes being different means that the objects are definitely *not* equal (provided `hashCode()` is correctly consistent `equals`).

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are correct, but here's an alternative way to look at it:  `hashCode` returns an `int`.  If you have an object that has a `String` as its only member and that string contains more than 4 bytes' worth of characters, then you already have more information in that `String` than can be expressed using an `int`.  Once you realise this, it becomes clear that there's no way the value returned by `hashCode` can be a complete representation of the object.

Since the value returned by `hashCode` can't completely represent the object, it clearly can't be used to determine whether the objects are semantically equal.

One thing you can do if the `hashCode`s of two objects are equal: you can assume there's a fairly reasonably chance that they're the same object.  Thus, e.g. `HashMap` first locates a hash bucket according to the hash code, but then looks through each object it finds there (using `equals`) to find an object semantically equivalent to the one you actually wanted.